# SFMC WSProxy / API: Is there a way to determine which BUs have access to a Shared or Synchronized DE folder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketingcloudapi, wsproxy

I'm working on an automated setup backup of synchronized data extensions in an multi-org account. There are multiple connections present and different business units have synchronized data extensions with names like:

- Account_Salesforce_1,
- Account_Salesforce_2,
- Account_Salesforce_3

I know the current state and could hard-code to which business unit set which DE belongs, but I want to make the process more dynamic and future-proof for a situation where the connections and names of synchronized data extension will change.

I would like to extract the information which business unit can access the data stored in each of the synchronized DEs.

<strike>Sadly, I don't see any data like this in the [SOAP API DataExtension object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextension.html) or the REST API reference.</strike>

**Update:**

I realized that all synchronized DEs for each of the connections share a `CategoryID` that's unique to a given connection.

To put it differently: each connection group has its own synchronized DE folder that we can retrieve from the [DataFolder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/datafolder.html) object (DataExtension CategoryID = DataFolder ID).

The base information we can get is this (the Name is always the same for this ContentType):

```js
{
  "ID": 123456,
  "Name": "Synchronized Data Extensions",
  "ContentType": "synchronizeddataextension"
}
```

I'm guessing the sharing mechanism will be similar to that of shared data extension folder, but I don't know how to retrieve data like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to retrieve shared DE Data folder privileges that allow business units to access data extensions inside them?

Comment: on the privileges - here is what I know DOESNT work... https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409527/define-control-policy-when-creating-a-de-via-api-allow-users-to-delete-data